# Glassfish: how to correctly deploy applications?

Tags: deployment, glassfish

My setup is as following:

Production web server with Glassfish 3.1.1 wrapped into a windows service.

Developing environment with Netbeans 7.1 with the included Glassfish server.

I thought a valid way to deploy updates to production server was to copy the content of the Netbeans /build directory and it worked well many times. 
Unfortunately I experienced a major problem, described in the link below, where new roles were not recognized because glassfish had cached data somewhere else.

[Glassfish: how to investigate roles/groups problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114410/glassfish-how-to-investigate-roles-groups-problems)

I checked the Glassfish configuration a lot but couldn't find any parameters like 'rebuild cached data at the server start'. So my question is how can I deploy updates in my production server being sure that my changes will not be invalidated by pre-compiled cached data ?

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: Why don't you use the redeploy command/feature? This should re-initialize your application and even is able to preserve sessions (sometimes).

Comment: Matt, FYI, that is a development-only feature and not recommended in production (and not supported in production) for commercial customers)

Comment: @JohnClingan Thanks. Interesting information... What is recommended in this case? We have a bunch of Glassfish Open Source servers in production and deploy and redeploy without any problems.

Comment: Ah, deploying, redeploying, and undeploying applications are all fine in production.  However, redeploying with Active Redeploy enabled (saving session state across redeploys) is a developer-only feature.